# Evaluating A Piecewise Function at a Point

Tags: evaluation, piecewise

Consider the following piece-wise function.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
$Assumptions = {L > 0};
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Subscript[A, 0] + Subscript[A, 1] x,  0 <= x < L/2}, 
                    {Subscript[B, 0] + Subscript[B, 1] x, L/2 < x <= L}}];
f[L/4]
```

The output which I get is the strange result

[image]

However, when I replace L with a numerical value then I get a correct output. What is going on here?

Comment: TIP: don't use subscripts.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: Does that solve this issue?

Comment: Nope.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assumptions` is (apparently) not automatically invoked by `Piecewise`.  However, by feeding this result to `Simplify` (or by defining `f[x_]` to include it), Mathematica does simplify things as expected:

```
Simplify[f[L/4]]

(* Subscript[A, 0] + (L Subscript[A, 1])/4 *)
```

Comment: Ah! You are right! Isn't this weird? :)